# regex to find any text outside tml tags c#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, regex

I need regex to find any text outside the html tags something like this :

```
<h1> Heading </h1>
Pargraph  1
<a href='../.../../'> Link</a>
Paragraph 2
<p>Text</p>
```

Regex find : 
Pargraph  1
Paragraph 2

Comment: Don't use regex, and why the mix of server (`c#`) and client (`javascript`) tags?

Comment: i removed the javascript tag how i can do it without regex ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use *positive lookbehind* and *positive lookahead*.

`(?<=<\/.*>)` matches the closing tag before matching text

`(?=<.*>)` matches the opening tag following the matching text

`[\w\d\s]*` - matches all words, digits and whitespaces

You can combine these expressions to get:

`(?<=<\/.*>)[\w\d\s]*(?=<.*>)` that will match all the words, digits and whitespaces between closing and opening html tag

`(?<=<\/.*>)[\w\d\s]*$` that will match all the words, digits after last closing tag

`^[\w\d\s]*(?=<.*>)*` that will match all the words, digits before first opening tag

**TL;DR:**

And you can combine these to get the expression that should solve your case:

`^[\w\d\s]*(?=<.*>)*|(?<=<\/.*>)[\w\d\s]*(?=<.*>)|(?<=<\/.*>)[\w\d\s]*$`